# Getting error as blank page when i click the mobile number which is responsive mode

Tags: wordpress

I add the following sample code 
 `<a href="callto://15555551212">+1 (555) 555-1212</a>` for mobile number into clickable when the website into responsive mode. But i'm getting the error as blank page when i check into mobile. Is there any possible ways to do in wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `//` and instead `callto://15555551212` it will be `callto:15555551212`

Comment: i tried like this also <a href="tel:(+1) 123.456.7700"> (+1) 123.345.7700</a> but its not working

Comment: Can you provide a link to your site please?